# How to avoid having my app shown in the list of recently used apps

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

On `Ice Cream Sandwich` the user can see a list of the recently used applications with a screenshot of the the last status of the `UI`.
I'm working on an application that shows confidential information that should not be kept in memory in any way.
Is there a way to disable that feature?

Comment: try `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in you activity manifest

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to the activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/your_app_name_goes_here"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:name=".SomeActivityNameGoesHere" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it by adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to all activities in your `AndroidManifest.xml` application manifest. Make sure to add it to all of them: if you only add it to one or some, your app won't always be excluded from the list of recently used apps.